# Turning binary into PDF in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, binary

I'm integrating with a third party ID verification provider. Once the ID verification checks have run a report is generated, which I can access with a `get` request.

The response is binary text (screenshot attached), which I want to save to a PDF file.

Function:

```
def generate_pdf
  resources = "applicants/61f84499b7b92f00014d5c6d/summary/report?report=applicantReport"
  response = RestClient.get(request_env_url(resources), signed_header(resources, nil, 'GET', 'application/pdf'))

  puts response
end
```

How do I take the binary response, create a new file and add the binary into that file in a friendly and readable format?

[image: Response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access a filesystem, you might just want to write that data to a file:

```rb
File.open("thing.pdf", "wb") { |f| f.write response }
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you. Works perfectly.

Comment: In case you have a minute for a follow up. How would I modify this line to specify the path for it? I saw `File.expand_path('~/Desktop/hello.pdf')` is the right method to use, but I don't know how to use it in combination with the line you already gave me.

Comment: `File.expand_path` returns a string, so you just use that string as first argument to `File.open`.

Comment: Awesome. This works, thanks! I can create a new question, but perhaps valuable for the next person that finds this thread. 

The use case is for the users of the web application, to be able to click a "Generate PDF" button and it would download on the users laptop OR open in a web page. 

For either of those two approaches, what are resources I should study?